# What should I do to switch off a P-Channel MOSFET as fast as possible?

Tags: mosfet, switching

I have a Power supply that powers `circuit A` (5V, up to 3A). When the power supply is disconnected I want to detect it and power `circuit B` with a battery (3.2V). I need `circuit B` to be powered on as fast as possible (it will keep alive part of `circuit A`) and want to keep the design as simple as possible.

To achieve this, I planed to use a P-Channel MOSFET where the gate would be connected to `Vin` (from power supply), source would be connected to `Vbattery` positive pole. and drain would be connected to `circuit B`. [See Circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsAoAJRAFoxCRsVX2o%20qaVJFRHQE9AM48OXEHiqyqEAGYBDADYSApvWVylNGvvDFuNCGDH76Ad2knuhI2FNQm9l9zYd2IvoM5obH4oMXoAJ2NZeXBDPjA4WyjuT05uSHo0clTZVIEQAGMAS3CCgFcigBcAfQBBTMhs11SWwnzi0oqagCF6AFkHNJAUAMVhsIGW1xGlVwVoFHoAc0GZ1YQODJXUmNTiTaT9wan0iMHc1xilaAwzk9WA69uADx5yBCRCDgQ8WnBuMoAOwADuoyksADoSCQ2KoFAAW9AARv9ft5hoQUmBhMjUbEOERuJhyBlXhgCcQkLgkChiL9nNxAQB7SpaABcUOUJQklShPNUSy0UKZyihHXKVSh3ShRQkUKRTKZPKhAEkAML0V4oIlgZw0cgoMDkBkgAAKLDV8KhACItID4apAQUtABbO2Va30IA)

Here are my questions:

- What should I do to switch off this P-Channel MOSFET as fast as possible (and power on `circuit B` as fast as possible)?
- What datasheet criteria should I take into consideration when chosing the MOSFET ?
- Well and of course, is there a better way to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this needs to be particularly fast?   If it actually did, a push/pull gate drive circuit would help overcome capacitance.  But what you are describing is a transition that likely has little consequence and happens rarely, not something like a commutation event that happens tens of thousands of times per second.

Comment: What may matter more is *detecting* the power loss when it happens, and now when capacitors in that supply have finished discharging, for that you may want a *comparator*.  Also you have the source and drain of your PFET swapped in your description - the *drain* goes to the load, unless you jump through the hoops to use an NFET as a high side switch.

Comment: Indeed the drain goes to the load and source to the battery... I must be tired. Thanks I'll fix the question. Regarding why I need it to be fast is because I want `circuit B` to keep alive a subset of `circuit A`.

Comment: First you'd put a substantial capacitor on that critical portion. Next, recognize that what you need is speed at *detection* and for that you want a comparator.  The title issue of turn-off speed seems to be unrelated to the actual issue.

Comment: If the power supply output is connected directly to the gate of the P-Mosfet, then the effect is immediate. He doesn't need a comparator. But adding a large capacitor is a good idea.

Comment: I've already put a rather large capacitor. I'm pretty sure you're more experienced than I am so I ok with recognizing that I rather need speed at detection if this is your opinion (I'm the one asking the question so I won't reject your suggestion). I just dont know in this context what should be compared to what and how to do it (if the power supply is disconnected, how should I power the comparator ? I would prefer not to use the battery if possible). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Fredled the MOSFET gate is connected to the power supply through a 100R pull up resistor.

Comment: Problem with simple solution (just a FET) is you need enough gate voltage to turn it on, and by then, supply voltage may have dropped enough so the circuit you want to power no longer has enough voltage before the FET turns on. Have you looked into ideal diodes and "power supply ORing" circuits? (try to search that, you'll find documents)

Comment: @bobflux No: With a P-MOSFET the problem is that you need enough voltage to turn it off. But since the voltage at the gate is provided by the power supply it will be higher than the source provided by the battery. So this is not a problem in this case.

Comment: It will be nice to post a schematic of your planned circuit so that we can improve it.